# Greatest two multiple of a number using PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a table in which column and rows are calculated dynamically from user entered number. For that I want to calculate nearest two numbers as column and rows from a number.

For example if a user entered 10 then the script calculate row as 3 or 4 and columns as 3 or 4 such as sum will become 10;

```
3*3+1 = 10
```

If someone enter 4 then 2 columns and 2 rows should generate. return 2 and 2
if it is 10 then 3 columns and 4 rows generates. return 3 and 4

Comment: Please explain it more clearly. Should the row no. and col no. be the same?

Comment: No...if someone enter 4 then 2 rows and 2 columns generate. if it is 10 the n 3 column and 4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to find the square root of your input and get the floor value. E.g: When input = 10, sqrt(10) = 3.16227766017.

Now, get the floor value i.e 3.
So, the dimension is 3 by 3.

Next, check if something needs to be added. The formula can be Nearest = Input - (Dimension * DImension)

So, the final calculation is Dimension * Dimension + Nearest(if not 0)

This will solve your purpose:

```
$dim = floor(sqrt($input));
$nearest = $input - ($dim * $dim);

if ($nearest) {
    printf("Nearest dimensions of %d = %d x %d + %d", $input, $dim, $dim,     $nearest);
} else {
    printf("Nearest dimensions of %d = %d x %d", $input, $dim, $dim);
}
```

When `$input = 4`, Output : `Nearest dimensions of 4 = 2 x 2`

When `$input = 10`, Output : `Nearest dimensions of 10 = 3 x 3 + 1`